# KeyError:'.' when parsing a number as string

Tags: python-3.x

When I run my code, it produces a `KeyError`

```
from functools import reduce   
DIGITS = {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9}

def str2float(s):
    dot_index=s.index('.')
    new_str = s[:dot_index]+s[dot_index:]
    print(new_str)
    return reduce(lambda x,y:x*10+y,map(lambda x:DIGITS[x],new_str))/(10**(len(new_str)-dot_index))

num = str2float('123.456')
print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting to float will solve your problem:

```
    numberInString = "123.456"
    numberInFloat = float(numberInString)
```

The variable "numberInFloat" is a floating point variable.
If you want an integer use int() instead, str() for strings.

Answer (score 0):

While parsing the stirng `"123.456"` your code encounters the `'.'` character, which is not in your dict.